# What is the name for this style of "bellows" water pump?

Tags: pumps, water-pressure

I recently bought this old "bellows" style water pump and would like to find spare parts for it - there is no nameplate or model number, and I don't even know what to call this sort of pump to ever begin to find parts for it.

Any ideas on what this type of pump is called?

[image]

Comment: You don't need to buy parts. The diaphragm is just sheet rubber sandwiched between the top and bottom housing. Everything else is stock parts from any farm supply or mechanical shop. The shaft frame looks to be repurposed from something else. But you could contact Edson pumps on the off chance it's one of theirs. https://www.zoro.com/edson-air-operated-diaphragm-pump-bronze-air-operated-nitrile-40-gpm-12059/i/G1599626/

Answer (score 3):

It is a diaphragm pump.

Another example is a diaphragm fuel transfer pump.

[image]

picture from homedepot.com

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a diaphragm pump, yes, but more specifically like a tire pump - the bellow is an actual tire with a plate flanged to it. I've seen these used in agriculture, with a motor and excenter like in your example, but with google image search I can only find toys.

You should be able to remove the collar (the one held by 4 large bolts) to see if the bellows is a tire, or if its a diaphragm as per jsotolas answer. Could be both tbh.

I don't have a farm or other need for heavy equipment. Specifically for a pump, it can pay off to check for spare parts availability, power consumption, etc. before buying.